# Pymongo aggregation: sum of the largest value between two fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Very new to mongo aggregation. My data looks something like:

```
{
    "type" : "rectangle",
    "length" : 4,
    "width" : 6
}
```

What I want to do is this: for each `type`, get the sum of x where x is whichever is the higher value between `length` and `width` in each record.

How would I do this?

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PeOhjNj-F1C) what you are looking for? Can you also give some expected output for your sampled data?

Comment: Figured it out, posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved, for anyone else who needs it:

```
{ $group: { _id : "$type", sum : { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "$length", "$width" ] }, 
                               then: "$length", else: "$width" } } }} }
```